# How to add control cells programmatically in a gridview C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Every row have to has a dropdownlist and a submit button.
So I made a List for data.
I added them like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Dkf.png)
//In my code behind

```
List<data> listdatainfo = new List<data>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
SqlDataReader detaillist = comm2.ExecuteReader();
 while (detaillist.Read())
 {
  rmainfo tempinfo = new rmainfo();
  tempinfo.itemdetail= detaillist["itemdetail"].ToString();
  tempinfo.creditmemo= detaillist["creditmemo"].ToString();
   tempinfo.submit= "0";//it will be filled 0 or 1
   listdatainfo .Add(tempinfo);
  }
  loadDataTable();}
```

//it was referenced from here http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/without-database.htm

```
private void loadDataTable()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt;
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn itemdetail;
        DataColumn creditmemo ;         
        CommandField submit = new CommandField();
        submit.EditText = "Edit";
        submit.ShowEditButton = true;

        itemdetail= new DataColumn("itemdetail",Type.GetType("System.String"));
        creditmemo = new DataColumn("creditmemo ",Type.GetType("System.String"));
        submit = new CommandField();
        dt.Columns.Add(itemDetail);
        dt.Columns.Add(creditMemo);
        dt.Columns.Add("submit"); //it's for submit button

        foreach (data tempinfo in listdatainfo )
        {
            DataRow dr;               
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Item Detail"] = tempinfo.itemDetail;
            dr["Credit Memo"] = tempinfo.creditMemo;
            dr["submit"] = submit;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView2.DataBind();    
       }}

public class data
    {

        public string itemDetail { get; set; }
        public string creditMemo { get; set; }
        public string submit { get; set; }
    }
```

As i expected, this line occured an error this line.
dr["submit"] = submit;

How can i add a button each row? or any component?
It was easier in classic asp.....
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the buttons in the GridView model instead of the datatable that is feeding it.

Comment: Thanks Joao. But how to do?

Comment: In the aspx page you have the gridview templates with all the column types and databoundfields (if needed). Just add a new column at the end of each template as a button. For further help post the grivview template here